# WooCommerce not recognizing child theme files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, child-theming

I am trying to modify the single-product.php template in WooCommerce. I follow the following steps:

1) Declare WooCommerce theme support by adding this to child theme functions.php:

```
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support' );
```

2) Create a new single-product.php template. I create this file in /child-theme/woocommerce/single-product.php. The file looks like the following, it's the same as the default template just adding some content at the bottom with the `do_shortcode` function

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single products
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[insert page="our-formulas-banner" display="content"]' ); ?>
<?php get_footer( 'shop' );

/* Omit closing PHP tag at the end of PHP files to avoid "headers already sent" issues. */
```

This works fine if I do it in the parent theme file, but not reading the child theme file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is the child theme is active?

Comment: @mujuonly yes it is